# SharePoint 2013, InfoPath 2010 error: 0x82000006

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, infopath, infopath2010

I've a SharePoint 2013 list modified with InfoPath. Everything was working fine until today, I had to do few modifications. While publishing the changes I'm getting the below error.

```
Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
<detail><errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    List does not exist.
    The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.
    </errorstring><errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x82000006</errorcode></detail>
```

Please let me know if there is a way to fix it.

Comment: Copy+Paste the list url inside InfoPath to the browser and check is is correct, try also a iisreset on sharepoint server.

Comment: It didn't help, although the main data connection in form(metadata) has a List ID that doesn't form a valid URL. Since the form  was published originally and was valid, how come it's throwing an error now?

Comment: Maybe the infoPath xml was broken, I do not remember GUID on main connection, try to recreate the main connection to the list, or try to open infoPath form with notepad to see what's wrong inside.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the exact same error message. In my case, the InfoPath Form was created with InfoPath 2010 and migrated to Sharepoint 2013. Editing with InfoPath 2013 yields the error message above. Editing with Infopath 2010 I can edit the form without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its because you have a lookup field in your list, and during import process the link to lookup list is broken